# Log SOAP header from ASMX Web Method

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx

How do I extract the request SOAP header information from within a C# Web Service Web Method?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to log the actual XML?

Answer (score 1):

First define a class that extends the SoapHeader class which members match the fields you want to access from your SOAP header:

```
public class MessageHeader : SoapHeader {
    public  string someHeaderParameter
}
```

Then within your WebService create an instance of this class:

```
public MessageHeader messageHeader;
```

And annotate your WebMethod like so:

```
[SoapHeader("messageHeader")]
```

Within your WebMethod you'll be able to access the header information:

```
messageHeader.someHeaderParameter
```